# Some metric to find research project for PhD program which lead me to kick the start-up after PhD

Tags: phd

I have trouble on finding my field.
 I have a master on computer networks in field  of Wireless Sensor Network. What I did on my master degree was just a pure simulation!

I like academia but What I am looking for is finding a research project which involve me on real world problems and not just simulation.

Ideally I want start my own start-up after finishing my PHD. or fining job in industry as a research associate which they research but they solve the real problems.

In order to more understanding you can see [here](http://www.forwardnetworks.com/) which they finish their thesis and start their own company.

Now my question is how to find a professor as supervisor which working with his project direct me to those what I said? For example If one professor has lots of citation on google-scholar one will make sure that he has strong knowledge on academia.

I need some metrics to know working with which professor will guarantee my working on industry as a research associate?

Are patents are good metric?

More example are:

In my thesis I have tool to develop which name was NS2. that is appropriate for simulation. I am sure working three to five years  with tools like that never directs me to solving real problem.

PS: 1. I did not said That I want to become developer on industry. 
Ps: 2. I say I want to become researcher which direct my to start my own start-up

Comment: to down voter : any reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, publication numbers and citation counts are a way to measure academic prowess. While patents are interesting as a metric, I wouldn't suggest they measure industrial relevance - I know several academics holding patents. None have ever actually been implemented into a product. None has any realistic and practical implementation, at least today. Now, don't get me wrong - one might become relevant in some years, but for now the patents were purely academic.

Instead I suggest taking a look at funding awards - at least in the UK there's a push towards industrially relevant research. Certain types of funding are given for partnerships with industry. For example, a TSB project (now Innovate UK) typically is either fully industrial, or industrial with academic partners. Someone with active and ongoing projects like this should be a good potential advisor.

Another potential way to approach the problem is to look for professors with their own spin-off companies. Generally universities like to shout and boast about their research which leads towards spin-offs! This is perhaps the most relevant indicator as to the industrial relevance of their work. To be clear, they typically hold their academic position while the spin-off company begins and trades, with the university encouraging it (and possibly holding a small investment stake).

Ultimately though, there isn't a reliable metric to guarantee that *you* would work on industrially relevant work as an RA. While you could certainly look at past industrial funding received (perhaps companies directly sponsoring PhD students), ultimately the only way to know is to talk to potential advisors. Perhaps current researchers too - if someone approached me having found my name on a paper, and asked about where the industrially relevant work was being led from, I could point them towards a few people who would be entirely happy to "promise" anything you worked on would be industrially relevant. Indeed I'm currently in the process of sorting out a new RA for a 100% industrial project.

As to metrics, I therefore suggest their own claimed funding, coming from non-academic sources (this will require some background research). The source of the money for their work generally highlights the motivation and (presence or lack of) industrial relevance. Ultimately you then need to talk to your short-list and see if they sound to be working on the things you want to work on.